# Create a concatenated string from json object in Python

Tags: python, json

From a json file, I have extracted the following:

```
[u'001', u'002', u'003', u'004', u'005', u'006', u'007', u'009', u'041', 
u'043', u'050', u'099', u'983']
```

But, what I need is to create a string like this (this will be part of a SQL statement)

```
str = """not in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','009','041','043','050','099','983')"""
```

I am new to this. Do you have any clues for me? 
This will be done in Python.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post what you've tried and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.join` wrapped in a `str.format` does the job. First & last quotes and parenthesis are handled by `format`, whereas middle quotes & commas are handled by `str.join`

```
s = [u'001', u'002', u'003', u'004', u'005', u'006', u'007', u'009', u'041',
u'043', u'050', u'099', u'983']

print("not in ('{}')".format("','".join(s)))
```

result:

```
not in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','009','041','043','050','099','983')
```

note that `str(tuple(s))` generates the same single quoted string, but I don't like relying on the representation of python objects.